# Object Detection, custom dataset, algorithm

Tags: classification, object-detection, opencv, yolo

I'm looking for a solution to detect objects and classify them, using a custom dataset.The overall goal is to detcet objects using my webcam.
So far I've wanted to use YOLO in combination with OpenCV, but I'm not sure how it'll work with overlapping objects. Is Instance Segmentation the better choice or does YOLO work fine? I've also read some information about Yolact, but am still unsure what to choose as it's my first project with DL. Please share your thoughts!
Thanks!

Comment: this tends to be opinion-based because it is vague